# Angular: How to generate one trans-unit from i18n attribute and $localize function?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

Code in component:

```
title = $localize`Monday`;
```

Code in template:

```
<div i18n>Monday</div>
```

"ng extract-i18n" command extract two separate trans-units to messages.xlf.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you have two separate translations that each get a random id like `id="ba0cc104d3d69bf669f97b8d96a4c5d8d9559aa3"` since you did not specify it. If you want to have only one trans unit you need to set a custom id:

```
title = $localize`:@@weekdayMonday:Monday`;

<div i18n="@@weekdayMonday">Monday</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the point here. 
Code in .html and in the .ts are maybe not related

Comment: Thanks @raphiki, you are right it seems like I missed the point here. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes I think using id is the only way to do this for now. The thing is that `ng extract-i18n` will generate one trans-unit if multiple occurence of the same text are found in different templates (without specify id, just the `i18n` attribute). I think it should also generate one trans-unit if the same text appears in a `$localize` method. Asked in the Angular Gitter but haven't got any response

Comment: Using IDs can be unefficient if many dev are working on the same app. They will have to always look at message.xlf if there is any occurence of his wanted text and create a custom ID and update both occurences with this id to avoid duplicating the trans-unit

Comment: We don't use IDs but instead, we use a 3rd party solution to handle the translation files for us. It merges the trans-units with the same text into one translation.

Comment: Can you tell me which tool you are using to do this?

Comment: https://poeditor.com/